# Set interval with background image changing caused a lag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, browser

I'm trying to create an animation switching between 2 images used as the background image of a div here's my code:

```js
var intervalloNavicella = setInterval(function() {
  if (accese == true) {
    var imageUrlSpacecrafat = "bk-nav-0" + currArea;
    $("#spacecraft").css(
      "background-image",
      "url(assets/img/" + imageUrlSpacecrafat + ".png)"
    );
    accese = false;
  } else {
    var imageUrlSpacecrafat = "bk-nav-0" + currArea + "-b";
    $("#spacecraft").css(
      "background-image",
      "url(assets/img/" + imageUrlSpacecrafat + ".png)"
    );
    accese = true;
  }
}, 500);
```

It works, the only problem is that during the changing sometimes there are some moments when the animation "lag" and there is no background image. This happens a lot of times and only for a few milliseconds.
Is this a browser problem or this is about my code?

Comment: How big are the images?  If you load a 4k image it can take some time for the browser to process this change.

Comment: The images are 1920x1211

Comment: quite big images probably in size thats why.

Comment: There isn't a way to make it work whitout downgrade the image quality?

Comment: Try to make them an img tag, and then hide or show the desired img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something like

```js
var intervalloNavicella = setInterval(function(){ 
  $('#spacecraft').toggleClass("spacecraftb")
}, 500);
```

```css
.spacecraft { 
  background-image : url(assets/img/bk-nav-0A.png);
}  

.spacecraftb { 
  background-image : url(assets/img/bk-nav-0B.png);
}
```

```html
<div id="spacecraft" class="spacecraft"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of high image quality. You can try to use 2 elements with loaded images, and toggle between them. Or decrease the quality of images.